# What's the new yarn 1.0.1 outdated output colors meaning?

Tags: yarnpkg

I've just upgraded yarn to `v1.0.1` and I've noticed that the output color is changed from only red/yellow to white/green/yellow/red...

What's the meaning of that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It only depends upon comparison of Current to Wanted:

- white - no change
- green - patch changed (last of the three)
- yellow - minor version changed (middle)
- red - major version changed or any
  change for pre-releases

The changed part of the version is also highlighted in the Wanted column.

Comment: so, if I do `yarn upgrade` I will upgrade only white and green?

Comment: No, it will upgrade everything else to white :-) The `Current` column shows what's in your `node_modules`, the `Wanted` column shows what's available and deemed safe to upgrade to according to the rules you specify in your `project.json` - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343224/whats-the-difference-between-tilde-and-caret-in-package-json). White means `Latest` is greater than `Wanted` so you have change your `project.json` to upgrade

Comment: is not a bit counterintuitive? White means more "safe" than dangerous, no?

Comment: Well, we're talking opinions now, not facts. You might think about it in terms of attracting your attention. Patch changed - probably a bug fix, might be important and unlikely to break things. So it's red - you should upgrade. White means a major version change - it might break your code. So, you're just gently warned with white.